# Sending data from wordpress to a facebook page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, api

Is there any suitable, secure and modular API to do this?
It will be included in a WP plugin.

EDIT: More that `posts` I need send generic data that it is collected through a WP plugin. These data is not stored in the WP DB, I just need send them.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://wordbooker.tty.org.uk/.

I am just a happy user of that plugin, no affiliation.

Comment: I have seen many related plugins. I asked for a suitable, secure and modular API. Thanks any way.-

Answer (score -1):

After 2 long and sad days I can contribute with this answer: This API is a very, very good. And it is recommended in the FB developer website to all your PHP needs:

[Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)